# Version control architecture for a large project with many dev groups

Tags: version-control, architecture, tfs, project-management

We are working on a very large portal project. We need a scalable source version control architecture such that, it should be scalable to many teams and possible incoming teams.

There will be common libraries and each group will work on different part of the system. At demo times, we need to integrate these parts and have the product testable, demoable and so on.

Do you recommend some guidelines or architectures?

How would you approach this problem?

In terms of version control system, we are using TFS, if it helps.

Comment: I actually find the answer here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668955.aspx

Comment: I almost voted to close this as not constructive. Please provide more detail on release patterns, shared stakeholders, etc. what's the current branch structure and what problems does it cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds to me you would be better off with a DVCS (Distributed Version Control System) like Git, rather than TFS which has a centralised version control system.

TFS now integrated with Git, here is a good blog post which provides you with most of the details you would need - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/01/30/getting-started-with-git-in-visual-studio-and-team-foundation-service.aspx

Add an enterprise level Git Repository Management tool like Atlassian Stash and life will be sweet - http://www.atlassian.com/software/stash/overview

Answer (score 0):

From a TFS server side...setup only 1 team project. This will be key. The other key is to have the server running SQL Server 2012 with SP1 (there's tons of perf improvements in SQL that will help you scale TFS).